# Android APK uploading failed using app signing by google play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

i want to upload a new app to the dev console and selected to enable app signing by google play. I usually sign my apps through the following gradle config and upload without issue

```
release {
    storeFile file("C:\\android_keystore.jks")
    storePassword "pass"
    keyAlias "my_key"
    keyPassword "pass"
}
```

However now am getting an error and am confused as to what i should be doing with my key now. I already have an app on the store i signed with the same key. But i only recently generated and uploaded the encrypted private key for that

```
You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in app signing by Google Play, you should sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a new key before you upload it.
```

Comment: i have created a new key and it worked. Though i cant seem to use this key in the gradle file like i did above. I need to go to build menu and generate signed apk and select new key from there

Answer (score 0):

is this the same key used before for app sining . as of playstore need same key to sign the app to upload.

Comment: yes, it works for my other app on the store. I was under assumption one key can be used for every app. Should i create one per app ?

Comment: it is not necessary to create different key for every app. one thing keep in mind that dont loose ur key coz if it differ google play will not approve u to upload any update version of ur app or like this.

Comment: i'll suggest u to make a universal key for ur every app to sign and store it in a safe place for future use

Comment: thats what i thought, i have one key, but its not letting me upload the new app with it